# JSession ID remains same after invalidate the session and request.getsession(true)

Tags: java, session, servlets, jsessionid

I am trying to invalidate the existing session and trying to create an new session for application after successful login/process. But JSESSIONID remains same before and after invalidating the session.

but prevsession.getId() and session.getId() is same.

```java
HttpSession prevsession = request.getSession(false);
        if (prevsession != null)
        {
            prevsession.invalidate();
        }
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

I expecting here is, request.getSession(true) will create an new JSESSIONID after invalidating session.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a defect and could be server container behavior where session IDs are used, sessions still remain unique.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. For my scenario I need to get different session id's, after invalidating and request.getSession(true). how can i get that?

Comment: @Franklin which servlet container/server are you using